# jQuery Validation not showing custom messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using the `jQuery Validation Plugin`. My validations are clearly working. However, my custom error messages are not displaying correctly?

- I am using **Unobtrusive** along with **Validation**

[image]

Thanks for the help...

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
dictionary.elements.form.validate({
    rules: {
        txtBSAPLocalAddress: {
            required: true
        },
        txtBSAPGlobalAddress: {
            required: true
        },
        txtBSAPDeviceLevel: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txtBSAPLocalAddress: "Local Address is required.",
        txtBSAPGlobalAddress: "Global Address is required.",
        txtBSAPDeviceLevel: "Device is required."
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="LocalAddress">
                <td>
                    <label for="txtBSAPLocalAddress">Local Address</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtBSAPLocalAddress" name="txtBSAPLocalAddress" placeholder="0 to 254..." required />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="txtBSAPLocalAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GlobalAddress">
                <td>
                    <label for="txtBSAPGlobalAddress">Global Address</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtBSAPGlobalAddress" name="txtBSAPGlobalAddress" placeholder="0 to 254..." required />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="txtBSAPGlobalAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="DeviceLevel">
                <td>
                    <label for="txtBSAPDeviceLevel">Device Level</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtBSAPDeviceLevel" name="txtBSAPDeviceLevel" placeholder="0 to 6..." required />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="txtBSAPDeviceLevel" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/ <-- this guy?  the messages belong to the rules they apply to, not an object definition on it's own.  Unless you got some documentation showing otherwise.

Comment: What custom error messages aren't having their validation applied? All three of the fields in your screenshot appear to have their `messages` being applied.

Comment: @ObsidianAge It's just saying "This field is required" instead of "Local Address is required"

Comment: `dictionary.elements.form.validate()` is going to be ignored because you're already using the Unobtrusive plugin, which automatically constructs `.validate()` for you.  Your instance will always be ignored.